# CsvHelper and immutable types

Tags: c#, csv

I have an immutable class that I want to write to and read from a CSV file. The issue is I am getting an exception when reading the CSV despite having mapped the object and set up a configuration that should allow this to work.

To do this I am using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). The immutable class looks like the following.

```
public class ImmutableTest
{
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public ImmutableTest(string name) : this(Guid.NewGuid(), name)
    {
    }

    public ImmutableTest(Guid id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I have no issue writing this to a CSV file, but when I try to read it from a file, I get the following exception.

> No members are mapped for type 'CsvTest.Program+ImmutableTest'

However, I have mapped the members for this class in the map class below.

```
public sealed class ImmutableTestMap : ClassMap<ImmutableTest>
{
    public ImmutableTestMap()
    {
        Map(immutableTest => immutableTest.Id)
            .Index(0)
            .Name(nameof(ImmutableTest.Id).ToUpper());

        Map(immutableTest => immutableTest.Name)
            .Index(1)
            .Name(nameof(ImmutableTest.Name));
    }
}
```

I have also tried to configure the reader to use the constructor to build the object by using the following configuration.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration
{
    IgnoreBlankLines = true
};

config.RegisterClassMap<ImmutableTestMap>();
config.ShouldUseConstructorParameters = type => true;
config.GetConstructor = type => type.GetConstructors()
    .MaxBy(constructor => constructor.GetParameters().Length)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

No of this seems to be working. Where am I going wrong?

---

Complete MCVE .NET Framework Console Example

Install the packages

```
Install-Package CsvHelper
Install-Package morelinq
```

Sample console program

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using MoreLinq;

namespace CsvTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Configuration config = new Configuration
            {
                IgnoreBlankLines = true
            };

            config.RegisterClassMap<ImmutableTestMap>();
            config.ShouldUseConstructorParameters = type => true;
            config.GetConstructor = type => type.GetConstructors()
                .MaxBy(constructor => constructor.GetParameters().Length)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            const string filePath = "Test.csv";
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(file))
            using (CsvSerializer csvSerializer = new CsvSerializer(fileWriter, config))
            using (CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(csvSerializer))
            {
                csvWriter.WriteHeader<ImmutableTest>();
                csvWriter.NextRecord();
                csvWriter.WriteRecord(new ImmutableTest("Test 1"));
                csvWriter.NextRecord();
                csvWriter.WriteRecord(new ImmutableTest("Test 2"));
                csvWriter.NextRecord();
            }

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(file))
            using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(fileReader, config))
            {
                foreach (ImmutableTest record in csvReader.GetRecords<ImmutableTest>())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(record.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine(record.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }

        public sealed class ImmutableTestMap : ClassMap<ImmutableTest>
        {
            public ImmutableTestMap()
            {
                Map(immutableTest => immutableTest.Id)
                    .Index(0)
                    .Name(nameof(ImmutableTest.Id).ToUpper());

                Map(immutableTest => immutableTest.Name)
                    .Index(1)
                    .Name(nameof(ImmutableTest.Name));
            }
        }

        public class ImmutableTest
        {
            public Guid Id { get; }

            public string Name { get; }

            public ImmutableTest(string name) : this(Guid.NewGuid(), name)
            {
            }

            public ImmutableTest(Guid id, string name)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue here is that there are no `ParameterMaps` in the class map.

The easy way to fix this, with the example above, is to write something like

```
public ImmutableTestMap()
{
    AutoMap();

    Map(immutableTest => immutableTest.Id)
        .Index(0)
        .Name(nameof(ImmutableTest.Id).ToUpper());
}
```

But this causes an issue that the column headers in the CSV file are `ID`, `Name` and the parameter maps generated are `id`, `name`. These are not equal to each other and so the reader throws an error saying it can't find a column with the name `ID`. It also says you can set header validated to null. After playing around with this, I ended up at a point where the configuration

```
Configuration config = new Configuration
{
    IgnoreBlankLines = true,
    ShouldUseConstructorParameters = type => true,
    GetConstructor = type => type.GetConstructors()
        .MaxBy(constructor => constructor.GetParameters().Length)
        .FirstOrDefault(),
    HeaderValidated = null,
    MissingFieldFound = null
};

config.RegisterClassMap<ImmutableTestMap>();
```

Is trying to parse empty fields and failing to convert it to a GUID. So it looked like that road was dead.

To get around this, I looked at checking each parameter map generated by auto map for the "id" value and then to replace it with "ID". However, this also did not work as the auto generated maps are generated with a null name. The name is only assigned when SetMapDefaults are called during the registration of a map in a config.

So I went for a blind loop of setting the names of the parameters maps to the explicitly defined member maps.

```
public ImmutableTestMap()
{
    AutoMap();
    Map(immutableTest => immutableTest.Id)
        .Index(0)
        .Name(nameof(ImmutableTest.Id).ToUpper());

    Map(immutableTest => immutableTest.Name)
        .Index(0)
        .Name(nameof(ImmutableTest.Id));

    if (MemberMaps.Count != ParameterMaps.Count)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MemberMaps.Count; i++)
    {
        ParameterMaps[i].Data.Name = MemberMaps[i].Data.Names[0];
    }
}
```

However, I would say this is more of a bodge than a fix and would definitely be open to other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the type is immutable, it will use constructor mapping instead. Your constructor variable names need to match the header names. You can do this using `Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch`.

```
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.AppendLine("Id,Name");
    s.AppendLine($"{Guid.NewGuid()},one");
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (header, indexer) => header.ToLower();
        csv.GetRecords<ImmutableTest>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

public class ImmutableTest
{
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public ImmutableTest(string name) : this(Guid.NewGuid(), name)
    {
    }

    public ImmutableTest(Guid id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What happens when the parameters have more than one word? Like the property `FirstName` and the constructor parameter `firstName`? A simple `ToLower` would not fix that issue. Do you have any advice?

Comment: @Dan With camelCase for your parameters, you can use `header[0].ToString().ToLower() + header[1..]` instead of `header.ToLower()`. Note that this syntax requires C# 8 but you can achieve the same result with different syntax with lower version of C#.